# pgAdmin 4 ver. 1.5 - no error messages

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I use pgAdmin 4 ver. 1.5. When I run an SQL query that has some issues (e.g. a column or a table does not exist) I can only see a message saying "Query returned successfully" but I cannot see any error message.

[image: please the screenshot below)]

[pgAdmin III 1.22.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaQ22.jpg)

However, pgAdmin III shows clearly SQL error messages in the same situation.
Is there any option in pgAdmin 4 to turn the error messages on? Or it's just a bug?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing in pgAdmin III?

Comment: I'm not able to re-produce it, check screenshot https://ibb.co/hZonav

Comment: @n33rma - and this exactly the message I would like to see in my pgAdmin 4 - unfortunately, I cannot.

Comment: @Colwin - please see the link above "pgAdmin III 1.22.2"

Comment: A screen from pgAdmin III https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaQ22.jpg

Comment: Can you check if the table exists with the following query? SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE 
      table_schema = '<schema_name>' AND 
      table_name = 'non_existing_table'
);

Comment: @Colwin - this table does not exist, as I have never created it. That query returns FALSE. My problem is, that when I query that 'non_existing_table' from pgAdmin 4 I cannot see any error message. While pgAdmin III clearly says the 'non_existing_table' does not exist.

Answer (score 13):

An issue is caused by non-English encoding.

I've experienced this issue within whole version 4 line. *psql* command line tool is affected too (spits out invalid chars complains instead of error messages).

Fix: open *postgresql.conf* file in your database directory. Find and comment out these lines, in my case had to wipe out Russian:

```
#lc_messages = 'Russian_Russia.1251'            # locale for system error message
                    # strings
#lc_monetary = 'Russian_Russia.1251'            # locale for monetary formatting
#lc_numeric = 'Russian_Russia.1251'         # locale for number formatting
#lc_time = 'Russian_Russia.1251'                # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
#default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.russian'
```

If you still want to see localized messages, you may want to try [sqlectron app](https://sqlectron.github.io/), it looks like to be nice backup tool for clumsy pgAdmin4.

Comment: Thank you - it helped. However, I needed to change only:  
  
**lc_messages = 'en_GB.UTF-8'**  <br>
  
and leave the other 3 parameters as they were before, when I created the database:    
  
**lc_monetary = 'Polish_Poland.1250'  
lc_numeric = 'Polish_Poland.1250'  
lc_time = 'Polish_Poland.1250'**
  
It works now and I can see all messages in pgAdmin 4 as well.

Comment: Commenting had no effect for me. I changed only **lc_messages** parameter: **lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'**, then reloaded configuration - now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I simply install the latest 4.3 version into the root directory of pgadmin, fixed the problem.....

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by installing pgAdmin language package if you're using Linux. At least for me this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by changing the below parameters from nonenglish langauge to english.

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'          
       # locale for system error message strings
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'          
             # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'           
           # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'              
           # locale for time formatting
```