# pgAdmin 4 version 1.6 doesn't shows any errors

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have faced with a problem - when I am executing query with some syntax error or special logic error - no error messages shows at all.

I've already tryed suggestions from this topic: [pgAdmin 4 ver. 1.5 - no error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195177/pgadmin-4-ver-1-5-no-error-messages)

But it didn't help.

Can anybody please give a suggestion ?