# How to show errors in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

If I make an error in the SQL query in pgAdmin then instead of explain error I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

How can I browse my errors in SQL queries?

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195177/pgadmin-4-ver-1-5-no-error-messages/44696759

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 finally the following worked: 
- Uninstalled PostgreSQL completely
- Installed again: during the installation there is a Locale dropdown box, which contains "Default". Changed that to "United Kingdom" ("USA" would work too I imagine).
After that pgAdmin started showing errors. 
(In English obviously, but that does not matter).